# New to Unity, GUI simply not showing up

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm very new to Unity, sorry if the question is too stupid, but all the information about GUI on Google focuses on the codes inside OnGUI() rather than the pre-setup.

The thing is, I created a project, created a javascript script with very simple code. That's all.

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {

}


function Update () {

}

function OnGUI () {
        GUI.Box(Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),"This is a Box");
        GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), "Hello World!"); 
}
```

After hitting Play button just nothing there.

Comment: You should look into the Unity [learning modules](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules). Also consider the fact that the `OnGUI` is much more suited for prototyping. (There is a beta out with the new GUI system that while not ready to be shipped out is more than far along for testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include that script to your scene camera[MainCamera]. Then it'll show ....

Comment: It doesn't actually have to be attached to the camera. Any gameobject will work.